# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: autoitx4java/AutoItX

Tags: java, autoit

I am getting the below errors when running my code. The code and installation instructions are based on the following links: https://github.com/accessrichard/autoitx4java and https://testguild.com/selenium-autoit/

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: autoitx4java/AutoItX
    at AutoITXSample.main(AutoITXSample.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: autoitx4java.AutoItX
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

This is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import autoitx4java.AutoItX;
import com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader;

import org.testng.Assert;

public class AutoITXSample {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        
        String jacobDllVersionToUse;
        if (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").contains("32")) {
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.20-x86.dll";
        } else {
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.20-x64.dll";
        }

        
        File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
        System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());
                

        AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
        String notepad = "Untitled - Notepad";
        String testString = "this is a test.";
        x.run("notepad.exe");
        x.winActivate(notepad);
        x.winWaitActive(notepad);
        x.send(testString);
        Assert.assertTrue(x.winExists(notepad, testString));
        x.winClose(notepad, testString);
        x.winWaitActive("Notepad");
        x.send("{ALT}n");
        Assert.assertFalse(x.winExists(notepad, testString));

    }

}
```

Comment: How are external dependencies mapped in your project? Do you have an external JAR that contains the class `AutoItX`? If so, does it exist inside the `autoitx4java` package?

Comment: In the lib folder:
  1. AutoItX4Java.jar
  2. jacob.jar
  3. jacob-1.20-x64.dll
  4. jacob-1.20-86.dll
In the tools folder:
  1. AutoITX3.dll
  2. AutoItX3-x64.dll

Jars have been added and appear under Referenced libraries.

In Referenced libraries:
AutoItX4Java.jar > autoitx4java (package) > AutoItX.class